# Anylogic discrete event modeling: How can I route my agent to multiple resource units based on if they are idle or busy in?

Tags: routes, anylogic

This scenario is for the Registration Process in a hospital.

I have 5 registration persons available to serve a patient to check in.
When a patient arrives, the patient needs to grab a register who is idle.
Assuming that patient 1 grabs register 1 and is still being serviced, when the second patient arrives, the patient needs to grab the second register so on and so forth.

When the first 5 patients arrive and assume that all are being serviced, the 6th patient has to wait.
If any of the registration persons are free, the patient needs to see him for service.

I tried this using `SelectOutput5` block with the condition `IsIdle` or `Isbusy`.

The model however routes patient to 1 registration person even if the person is busy.

I believe I am missing some pieces.

Comment: you just need 1 service block and 5 resources... why do you need a selectoutput5?

Answer (score 0):

As per my previous answer and Felipes comment: this is exactly what a Service object is doing, if you link it with a Resourcepool.

Do that and it will work. Check example models to learn more about how to use them, just search for "service" or similar